# How can I cache a passphrase for use in a script that uses gpg2 --symmetric with STDIN?

Tags: linux, bash, security, encryption, gnupg

I am working on a computer program that stores and retrieves secrets and needs to run without user interaction on the server.

I have successfully set everything up in my system to use `gpg-agent` to retrieve the cached passphrase without user interaction to encrypt and decrypt data with `gpg2 --symmetric` *when I specify a file name*.

However, this requires me to temporarily store my data on the disk without encryption.  I do not want to put unencrypted data on my disk.  So now I have changed things to work with STDIN and STDOUT rather than disk files.

The command I am testing with is this: `cat test.txt | gpg2 --symmetric -o test.gpg`.

The problem is that now it does not seem possible to get the passphrase cached and so I must enter it interactively each time.  This will not work for my server program.

I have tried using gpg-preset-passphrase for this.  I do not know if it is possible though because it wants a "KEYGRIP".  One rough idea I have is this: maybe there is some default keygrip that gpg2 uses with --symmetric and STDIN.  But I don't know if that idea will pan out.

I am not planning to specify a passphrase in my code with --passphrase because that means I need to store a secret in the code, which I am not going to do.. and it would allow anyone who could access the code to decrypt the files.  It would also expose the passphrase on the command line.

I hope that it is clear enough what I am trying to achieve.  Any ideas are appreciated.

Comment: How were you caching the passphrase initially?

Comment: gpg-agent does it when it has a file name.

Answer (score 5):

I recently struggled with this and (after endless stumbling around gpg docs and qa sites) came across this [2015 thread](https://lists.gt.net/gnupg/devel/72314) that mentions the answer:

> > Maybe what i'm missing is how the "cache_id" is selected for the
> > symmetric passphrase, both at creation time and at re-use time. can you
> > summarize that? I dug around in the code a bit but didn't sort out how
> > it's being done.
>
> If I remember correctly (and the logic hasn't changed), it is a
> randomly chosen 8-octet salt value:
> https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4880#section-3.7.1.2

> ...

> The S2K salt is used as cache id.

You can get the salt by listing packets for your encrypted file:

```
$ echo | gpg --list-packets ~/myencryptedfile 2>&1 | grep -o '[0-9A-F]\{16\}'

0123456789ABCDEF
```

- leading `echo` forces `Inappropriate ioctl for device` error, bypassing pinentry prompt
- `2>&1` hide stderr
- `grep -o '[0-9A-F]\{16\}'` extract salt from command output

Now we have the 8-octet hex-encoded salt value.

Unfortunately that didn't work directly for me. So after more stumbling around the gpg codebase, I came across [this snippet](https://github.com/gpg/gnupg/blob/54f88afba4564e62e51fe6e22beabbdee75f91ac/g10/passphrase.c#L327-L330):

```c
  memset (s2k_cacheidbuf, 0, sizeof s2k_cacheidbuf);
  *s2k_cacheidbuf = 'S';
  bin2hex (s2k->salt, 8, s2k_cacheidbuf + 1);
  s2k_cacheid = s2k_cacheidbuf;
```

The crux is the "S" prepended on the second line. I couldn't find this mentioned anywhere else.

So all together now. Encrypt the file:

```
$ gpg --symmetric --passphrase-fd 3 --batch --output ~/myencryptedfile <<EOF 3<<EOF3
> myencryptedcontent
> EOF
> mypassphrase
> EOF3
```

- `--passphrase-fd 3`: supply passphrase over file descriptor 3
- `--batch`: required with `--passphrase-fd`
- I prefer to supply passphrase via `--passphrase-fd 3` and data to be encrypted over stdin (`<<EOF` and `3<<EOF3`) rather than write it to a file initially for `cat`, or echoing it into stdin (which makes me fearful of process list snooping). Docs: [here-documents](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html) (EOF syntax).
  Bash [here-strings](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/x17837.html) are more syntatically palatable (eg. `gpg --symmetric ... ~/myencryptedfile <<<myencryptedcontent 3<<<mypassphrase`) but WILL leave the passphrase in bash history, so they're best avoided in this use-case.

Get the 8-octet hex salt value:

```
$ echo | gpg --list-packets ~/myencryptedfile 2>&1 | grep -o '[0-9A-F]\{16\}'

0123456789ABCDEF
```

Make sure passphrase reset is allowed by gpg-agent:

```
$ cat ~/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf
allow-preset-passphrase

$ gpg-connect-agent reloadagent /bye  # restart the agent after changing config
```

Preset the passphrase:

```
$ /usr/local/Cellar/gnupg/2.2.17/libexec/gpg-preset-passphrase --preset S0123456789ABCDEF <<EOF
> mypassphrase
> EOF
```

- **"S" prefixed onto the salt,** so the resulting gpg-agent cacheid is
  `--preset S0123456789ABCDEF`
- passphrase over stdin via heredoc (EOF) to avoid it showing up in the process list
- If you get `ERR 67108924 Not supported <GPG Agent> - no --allow-preset-passphrase`, you need to add `allow-preset-passphrase` to `~/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf` and restart the agent (see above)
- The location of `gpg-preset-passphrase` may be different on your system.

And finally, decrypt the file!

```
$ gpg --decrypt --pinentry-mode loopback ./myencryptedfile
gpg: AES encrypted data
gpg: encrypted with 1 passphrase
myencryptedcontent
```

Notes:

- I've found locating `gpg-preset-passphrase` in my scripts annoying since it isn't installed anywhere on the system path (at least not in my installation). However, `gpg-connect-agent` is, and can be used for the same purpose with an additional step. You just need to hex-encode the passphrase before using it (`tr -d '\n'` because EOF adds a newline):

```
$ (tr -d '\n' | hexdump -v -e '/1 "%02X"' && echo) <<EOF
> mypassphrase
> EOF
6D7970617373706872617365

$ gpg-connect-agent <<EOF
> preset_passphrase S0123456789ABCDEF -1 6D7970617373706872617365
> EOF
OK

# now decryption should work as above
```

- I'm running gnupg version 2.2.17 on OSX, installed via homebrew

```
$ gpg --version
gpg (GnuPG) 2.2.17
libgcrypt 1.8.5
```

Comment: I'm down this pathway with you and... is this really acceptable??  Adoption of gpg encryption seems pretty unlikely until this kind of nightmare is resolved.  It seems like such a basic use case: decrypt a file into memory without plaintext on disk.  Am I missing something?

Comment: Also, this leaves the passphrase in the bash history it seems?

Comment: I'm fully with you, this seemed shockingly complex to me. Not having too much past involvement with gpg, my only guess is that --symmetric mode and gpg-preset-passphrase are less fleshed-out feature sets since gpg is primarily intended to be interacted with via key pairs, not passphrases.

Comment: On my system it seems that using heredocs to supply the passphrase does _not_ leave it in history (`gpg-connect-agent <<EOF` and passphrase on next line) but the shorter <<< bash "here-string" syntax does. Very good reason to use the heredoc method, along with portability.

Comment: I've edited the original answer which had mentioned here-strings as a possible alternative, thanks for the call out @moodboom.